# Update on libmysqlclient20 fails on a 16.04.1 LTS machine

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I am wondering how I can figure out the exact reason why installing a package fails.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) on two different machines and on one of them I get the message below while upgrading libmysqlclient20 but on the other machine it works without any problems.
 I ran the update there as well and that just went like normal.

The file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient20:amd64.triggers' is empty even though the update tells me to look in there for the error.

The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient20
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/809 kB of archives.
After this operation, 67.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 101820 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient20_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient20_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 read error in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient20:amd64.triggers': Input/output error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient20_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

So what can be done to make sure that the update will run on this server as well without any problems?? Any help with that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: solution???? same prob with "read error in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libqt5test5:amd64.triggers': Is a directory"